# There are 2 tables in SQL Customer and Transaction, Display the customer details who has done maximum number of transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, sql-order-by

Following are the table Attributes:

1. Customer Table: Customer ID, Customer Name, Address, Email ID and Mobile Number.
2. Transaction Table: Transaction ID, Transaction Type, Amount and Customer ID.

Comment: What result do you need if a lot of customers have the same and maximum number of transactions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can join the customer table with an aggregate query that computes their count of transaction:

```
select c.*, t.cnt
from customers c
inner join (select customerid, count(*) cnt from transactions group by customerid) t
    on t.customerid = c.customerid
order by t.cnt desc
limit 1
```

If you don't need to display the count of transactions in the resultset, you can also use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select c.*
from customers c
order by (select count(*) from transactions t where t.customerid = c.customerid) desc
limit 1
```

If you want to allow top ties, then one option is to use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0 only):

```
select c.*
from customers c
inner join (
    select customerid, count(*) cnt, rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from transactions 
    group by customerid
) t on t.customerid = c.customerid
where t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @number_of_transactions INT = --(YOUR DESIRED MAXIMUM NUMBER OF TRANSACTION)
```

```
SELECT * FROM customer_table a INNER JOIN transaction_table b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id WHERE COUNT(b.transaction_id) = @number_of_transactions
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Comment: Hey !! Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain the first line " DECLARE @number_of_transactions INT = --(YOUR DESIRED MAXIMUM NUMBER OF TRANSACTION) "

Comment: It's like you declare a variable ex. var x = 5;. Sorry late reply.